# Kryonet: discovery host always return null

Tags: networking, udp, kryonet, device-discovery

I try to use Kryonet to create an online game.

When I give the ip address (hardcoded in the code), connection and sending/receiving works.

But if I try to discover the server, it's never responding me: the method always return null.

Server:

```
public static int UDP_PORT = 54723, TCP_PORT = 54722;
public static void main(String args[]) {
   
    /* ***** server starting ***** */
    Server server = new Server();
    server.start();
     
    try {
        server.bind(TCP_PORT, UDP_PORT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("server not deployed");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("server started");
    server.addListener(new ServerListener());
}
```

Client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client client = new Client();
     
    client.start();
    InetAddress addr = client.discoverHost(UDP_PORT, 10000);
    System.out.println(addr);
    if(addr == null) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
     
    try {
        client.connect(5000, addr, TCP_PORT, UDP_PORT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        client.sendTCP(new String("bouh" + i));
    }
     
    client.close();
}
```

What's wrong in this code?
Note that my tests are launched on localhost. Is it a problem here?

Thanks for all response.

Jonathan

Comment: Have you enabled logging to determine why discovering the host is failing? http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/#Logging

Comment: hello!  

Ah, sorry, I can't see this issue.  

My probleme has resolved when I just add this instruction in my client:  
`System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");`  

Thank's all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having the same problem I had related to discover hosts (http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/issues/detail?id=29) then checking out the project from SVN (instead of using the 2.20 zip file) fixed the issue for me.